# Maven plugin for auto formatting code to match google checkstyle?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm using the google checkstyle in Intellij: https://github.com/google/styleguide

I have this eclipse checkstyle run when I format during any coding in IntelliJ and it seems to work fine. I want to have a Maven phase that formats the code whenever I run `mvn clean install`.

I'm using the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
    <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>format</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>src/main/resources/eclipse-java-google-style.xml</configFile>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be registering that config file properly. I'm wondering what the best rule of thumb is for grabbing the proper checkstyle config. Where to I put it and how do I represent it in my POM?

Answer (score 14):

According to [formatter-maven-plugin](http://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/examples.html#Custom_Configuration_File) documentation's example "Basic configuration using external resource", you have to remove the "src/main/resources/" in :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
<artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>format</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <configFile>eclipse-java-google-style.xml</configFile>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Ryan, if it did solve your problem, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Hi @Guillem, This worked for me. Thank you so much. Can I apply this code format during git-commit? Many times it happens that, people do not execute mvn commands before pushing the code. If somehow I can add this as a git commit hook, it can help a lot.

Comment: @mitmehta one option is to have an action that runs on each pull request, and fails if the code needs to be reformatted. That way all merges are of code that has already been correctly formatted.